# Error 580 sending confirmation code request to Skype using Skype4Java

Tags: java, skype, skype4java

I'm trying to verify a phone number to be used as reply-to when sending Skype messages. I'm using the Skype4Java library.

When I invoke the method submitConfirmationCode with the number I want to confirm, Skype returns Error 580: ALTER SMS Failed. Digging deeper into the library, what happens is that it creates a new message with the command:

```
CREATE SMS CONFIRMATION_CODE_REQUEST 1234567890
```

Which succeeds returning an SMS COMPOSING message with the ID. When the library tries to send it, using:

```
ALTER SMS [ID] SEND
```

It fails with the error 580. All of the previous steps are correct according to the API reference in skype's page. Error code 580 is not even listed.

Has anyone faced a similar situation?
Thanks!

Comment: Clarification: the message is sent nevertheless, but I would like to obtain a confirmation that it was sent successfully, not a 580 error.